# IIF condition in Azure Synapse Derived Columns

Tags: azure-synapse

In the 'Azure Synapse Derived Columns' section, I'm attempting to create a simple conditional expression using a CASE-WHEN or IF statement. However, it's not working as expected. What I'm trying:

iif(VERIFICATION_DATE != null, 'Y', null)
iif(isnull(VERIFICATION_DATE), null, 'Y')

did not work, got mismatch type issue, i would like to understand why.

I just need to bring null when VERIFICATION_DATE is null and 'Y' when VERIFICATION_DATE  is not null

iif(VERIFICATION_DATE != null, 'Y', null)
iif(isnull(VERIFICATION_DATE), null, 'Y')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting type mismatch is because, null function gives null as return type whereas `'Y'` is of string type.
So, you convert null type to string inside if condition as below.

```
iif(isNull(cc), toString(null()), 'Y')
```

Output:

[image]